# Get all the selected options on each onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several select element generated by a map. Aside from using  jQuery to access the dom elements is there a way to get all the selected values onChange

```
changed = () => {
 // Keep track of all the selected options
}
[1,2,3].map(value => (
<select onChange={changed}>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>)
```

Whenever I select an option I would like to keep track of the option selected in an array. If in the first select I chose 1 then the second one 2 I'd like to have an array [1,2] representing the options picked. If I then select the third option to be 3 then the new array should be [1,2,3].In this case I want three separate select and I want to keep track the options selected in each

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's not much to work off of here. Can you show your `changed` function and enough code to create a [mcve]? I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ggorlen I did an edit on the question maybe this time it's more clear. I hope...

Comment: She’s trying to add the options value to an array that only contains a list of selected options. Ie every time a option is selected it should add that value to the array and when unselected it should remove the value from the array. Maybe make the array index and value the same or the index can be the option value and the value of the array can be 1 for true that way selecting the array index is easier since she can selected[HTMLElement.value].push and selected[HTMLElement.value].pop

Comment: Well I would suggest there be a way to remove an option but after looking at the question again she is only wanting to add the value to the array each time a value is selected so I guess push the values and if she wants them to be in order than she can use the sort option, sorry I don’t answer because I have not actually worked out the solution because I am not at my computer and coda for iOS is really slow lol

Answer (score 0):

Assume you use hooks in your code. This should be like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

    const App = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("selections: ", selections);
      });
      const [selections, setSelections] = useState({});

      const changed = (value, e) => {
        setSelections({ ...selections, [`${value}`]: e.target.value });
      };

      return (
        <div>
          {[1, 2, 3].map(value => (
            <select key={value} onChange={e => changed(value, e)}>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
          ))}
        </div>
     );
   };

export default App;
```

*UPDATE*: I updated my solution, sorry for missunderstand your questions, in case of multi dropdown list, your state should construct this way:

`{ "1": 1, "2": 3, "3": 1}`

Key is dropdown identifier and value is the selected option for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've written examples using both React class and functional component for you.

If you want to use select with multiple values, you will have to set select `multiple` attribute to `true`. Note that select is very difficult to style and you may consider using a custom **Dropdown** instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ClassExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: [],
  }

  handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const { value: selectedValue } = e.target;
    const { value } = this.state;
    const newValue = [].concat(value);
    const index = newValue.findIndex(v => v === selectedValue);
    if (index > -1) {
      newValue.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      newValue.push(selectedValue);
    }
    this.setState({ value: newValue });
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          value={value}
          multiple
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
        >
          {[1, 2, 3].map(v => <option key={v} value={v}>{v}</option>)}
        </select>
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const FunctionExample = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const { value: selectedValue } = e.target;
    const newValue = [].concat(value);
    const index = newValue.findIndex(v => v === selectedValue);
    if (index > -1) {
      newValue.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      newValue.push(selectedValue);
    }
    setValue(newValue);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        value={value}
        multiple
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      >
        {[1, 2, 3].map(v => <option key={v} value={v}>{v}</option>)}
      </select>
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => (
  <>
    <label>
      Class : <ClassExample />
    </label>
    <label>
      Function : <FunctionExample />
    </label>
  </>
)

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-controlled-multiple-select-g7shd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark